# Set field format in query to report

Tags: ms-access, format

Is there a way for a report's field to take into account the format of a field in a query?

In example:

I have a StudentPercent field in a query. Values of the field are between 0 to 1, but since it is formatted to percent, they appear from 0% to 100% . When I run the report, it doesn't consider the format of the field and the values are between 0 to 1. Why is that?

Edit 1: I'm using Microsoft Access 2016.
Also, datas are populated dynamically, so I can't just set the format of the fields manually.

Edit 2:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
'Exit Sub
'  Place values in text boxes and hide unused text boxes.

    Dim intX As Integer
    '  Verify that not at end of recordset.
    If Not rstReport.EOF Then
        '  If FormatCount is 1, place values from recordset into text boxes
        '  in detail section.
        If Me.FormatCount = 1 Then
            Me("Col" + Format(intColumnCount + 1)) = 0
            For intX = 1 To intColumnCount
                '  Convert Null values to 0.
                Me("Col" + Format(intX)) = Nz(rstReport(intX - 1))
                If intX < intColumnCount Then
                    Me("Col" + Format(intColumnCount + 1)) = _
                    Me("Col" + Format(intColumnCount + 1)) + Nz(rstReport(intX))
                End If
            Next intX

            '  Hide unused text boxes in detail section.
            'For intX = intColumnCount + 2 To conTotalColumns
                'Me("Col" + Format(intX)).Visible = False
            'Next intX
        For intX = 2 To intColumnCount + 1
            Me("Tot" + Format(intX)) = Nz(Me("Tot" + Format(intX))) + Nz(Me("Col" + Format(intX)))
        Next intX

            '  Move to next record in recordset.

            rstReport.MoveNext
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

^ is the code of the detail part of my report. 
I'm getting the error '13' - Type mismatch when I run the report after casting my field with Format(FieldName, "Percent") and the following code is highlighted:

```
                Me("Col" + Format(intColumnCount + 1)) = _
                Me("Col" + Format(intColumnCount + 1)) + Nz(rstReport(intX))
```

Comment: It's probably just that you forgot to specify a *ValueIfNull* for the `Nz` function which causes the function to return a zero-length string (which can't be added to a number). Try `Nz(rstReport(intX), 0)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the *Format* property of the textbox in the report to: Percent

Or, expand the source query to have a field returning the formatted value as text:

```
StudentPercentText: Format([StudentPercent],"Percent")
```

Then use this field in your report and not the StudentPercent field. However, this is text, so you cannot use such a field in a calculation in the report.

Comment: I prefer not to set the format of the report's field, since they are all unbound - I tried to use the second method, however I'm getting an error '13'. I've edited my question with details following the modification.

Comment: @Misen When not binding the controls to the fields of the query, you can't expect that the format is taken from the query. The "format" property is nothing but a way to tell Access how to display a field's content when the field is bound to a control. It's **not** a way to "fomat the values" (values don't have a format). Your code assigns values to controls that you don't want to configure with a format, so there IS not format.

Comment: @Wolfgang Kais Thanks for the explanation - I had the wrong perspective about it. However, using the Format(Fieldname, "Percent") generated an error '13' when I ran the report and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Misen Try to use `Format(Fieldname, "0.00 %") instead.

Comment: @Misen Well, I guess that's because you are now trying to add numbers and strings (the result of the `Format` function is usually a string). So I suggest to perform the addition in a variable and assign the formatted value from the variable to the control.

Comment: @WolfgangKais is right. I've added a note in my answer. You will have to apply the percent format to the Format property of the textbox holding the final value.